# Spec sheet diagram re: NEC u7225PD LCD Driver (14 segments)

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, driver, lcd, counter

This question is in regards to [figure 6 of the uPD7225 Programmable LCD Controller/Driver data sheet](https://www.lcd-module.de/eng/pdf/zubehoer/upd7225.pdf#page=13). My use case is typical: a 14 segment driver clocked at 147k in divide-by-four mode.

From the datasheet it would seem:

1. 14 segment driving requires divide/4 mode (Figure 4 of linked)
2. Segment decoding should be commanded 'ON' (Section 8.9 of linked.)
3. The MSbit in the data word of a decoded 14 segment character should be high. (Section 2.4 of linked.)
4. The data word for a 14 segment decoded byte will "correspond to 8-bit ASCII code" (bottom of Figure 4 of linked)

In the context of the four statements above I cannot make sense of the chart on (lucky) page 13.

My stupor is vaguely bounded by these questions:

1. If the data word is one byte, why does the chart have a vertical axis of lower bits (shown as a nibble from 0-F) and a horizontal axis of 4-tuples (n+3 to n)?
2. How to interpret the 4-tuple? Is the data value for a character different depending on where it is written in memory?
3. How do the axes intersect to make an 8bit value?
4. Why don't the 8bit values look like ASCII? (Eg: "A" 65 aka 0x41)
5. Why aren't the MSbits of ALL the Horizontal axes number "1"? (^^req'd for 14 seg decoding)

Can anyone tell me how to read this page such that I can know the values to write for the characters shown?

Comment: look at figure 4 ... each digit us driven as a 4x4 matrix